# Making Predictions on iris species with logisitc regression

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, iris-dataset

I have a given code that tells you if an Iris from the iris dataset is an iris vireginica or not, based on the petal length and petal width. But how do i make prediction with a completely new flower?

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
iris = datasets.load_iris()

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = iris["data"][:, (2, 3)]  # petal length, petal width
y = (iris["target"] == 2).astype(np.int)

log_reg = LogisticRegression(C=10**10, random_state=42)
log_reg.fit(X, y)

x0, x1 = np.meshgrid(
        np.linspace(2.9, 7, 500).reshape(-1, 1),
        np.linspace(0.8, 2.7, 200).reshape(-1, 1),
    )
X_new = np.c_[x0.ravel(), x1.ravel()]

y_proba = log_reg.predict_proba(X_new)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.plot(X[y==0, 0], X[y==0, 1], "bs")
plt.plot(X[y==1, 0], X[y==1, 1], "g^")

zz = y_proba[:, 1].reshape(x0.shape)
contour = plt.contour(x0, x1, zz, cmap=plt.cm.brg)


left_right = np.array([2.9, 7])
boundary = -(log_reg.coef_[0][0] * left_right + log_reg.intercept_[0]) / log_reg.coef_[0][1]

plt.clabel(contour, inline=1, fontsize=12)
plt.plot(left_right, boundary, "k--", linewidth=3)
plt.text(3.5, 1.5, "Not Iris-Virginica", fontsize=14, color="b", ha="center")
plt.text(6.5, 2.3, "Iris-Virginica", fontsize=14, color="g", ha="center")
plt.xlabel("Petal length", fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("Petal width", fontsize=14)
plt.axis([2.9, 7, 0.8, 2.7])
plt.show()
```

Now lets say i have a new flower an i measure:

- sepal length: 4.8
- sepal width:  2.5
- petal length: 5.3
- petal width:  2.4

When i try the follow prediction, i get an error says: 
**ValueError: X has 1 features per sample; expecting 2**

```
log_reg.predict([[5.3], [2.4]])
```

So my question is, how do i correclty make predictions here about a new flower and what kind of species it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `predict` method says that the input argument should be of shape `(n_samples, n_features)` i.e. 1x2 here, whereas the input in your case is 2x1. Try this:

```
log_reg.predict([[5.3, 2.4]])
```